# linux paging, using a lot of page table directories

Tags: linux, paging, page-tables

I read the book Mel Gorman about Linux virtual memory. 
I have read, that Linux support 3 level of page tables: PGD,PMD and PTE. If i am not mistaking in newer version of kernel, there are four page tables level: PUD, but it doesn't matter. I have a reasonable question. 
Why Linux developer choose 3(or 4) level of page tables instead of using one? The using only one global page table(i mean global page table per process) will decrease the amount of memory reference.

Sorry for my English please.

Comment: You're probably better off asking the Linux mailing list, or whatever communication mechanism they use; a lot of us on SO are unlikely going to know the justifications for every design detail of Linux.

Comment: It's the exact opposite of your assertion. Using a single level page table would require an entry for every single page (at least a pointer) to be allocated in that single table. By having multiple levels of page table, apart from the top level, all other levels can be left unallocated until that part of the address space is used.

Answer (score 0):

It's the exact opposite of your assertion. Using a single level page table would require an entry for every single page (at least a pointer) to be allocated in that single table. By having multiple levels of page table, apart from the top level, all other levels can be left unallocated until that part of the address space is used. – kaylum